# How many seven digits can we form with four 1's and three 2's?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The answer says that it is $35$ due to choosing $4$ out of $7$ slots.

Is this because once we have chosen where the four $1$'s go, the $2$'s have to fall into the gaps or is there another reasoning?

I ask because at first I thought the answer would be ${}_7 C_4 + {}_7 C_3$?

Comment: The argument you give for $\binom 74$ is correct.

Comment: There is only one seven digit.  It is absurd to try to make another seven digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah. It's $ ^7 C_4 $ or $ ^7 C_3 $ whatever you wish to say as both have same value equal to 35. You choose the gaps for any one number in that many ways and the other number goes in the remaining positions.

Answer (score 2):

It is just $7 \choose 4$: you can think of it as there being $7$ locations for the digits, and choosing $4$ of those for a $1$ to go into.  However, ince the $1$'s are in place, all the $2$ have to go in the remaining spots, so there are no further options.

Of course, you can also start with the $2$'s and choose $3$ out of the $7$ spots for the $2$'s to go into.  That gives you $7 \choose 3$ possibilities. Once the $2$'s are in their location, the $1$'s are now fixed as well, so again that's it.

So, the answer is either $7 \choose 4$ or $7 \choose 3$. Fortunately (well, logically they *had* to to be the same) they both evaluate to $35$